# What do you call the fact of ignoring certain facts purposely?

Tags: word-request

For example, politicians say that "Medicare for all" is realistic without mentioning that their plan require drastic cuts to the military budget, which can come with very dire consequences. What do you call such a deliberate act? Is there a name for it?

For example:

> The politician ignored certain facts of the matter when asked about
>   the financial implications of his policies. He was ___.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - He was **deceiving**.

or:

> - He was a **deceiver**.

or:

> - He was **deceitful**.

---

> [**deceive**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deceiving) (verb) = to persuade someone that something false is the truth, or to keep the truth hidden from someone for your own advantage:
>
> - The company deceived customers by selling old computers as new ones.
> - The sound of the door closing deceived me into thinking they had gone out.

also:

> [**deceiver**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deceiving) (noun) = someone who deceives people